# Cross domain Ajax request from within js file

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Here's the problem:

1.) We have page here... www.blah.com/mypage.html

2.) That page requests a js file www.foo.com like this...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.foo.com/jsfile.js" />
```

3.) "jsfile.js" uses Prototype to make an Ajax request back to www.foo.com.

4.) The ajax request calls www.foo.com/blah.html. The callback function gets the html response and throws it into a div.

This doesn't seem to work though, I guess it is XSS. Is that correct?

If so, how can I solve this problem? Is there any other way to get my html from www.foo.com to www.blah.com on the client without using an iframe?

Comment: There is really a nice article regarding cross domain ajax request - http://tek-insight.blogspot.com/2010/05/cross-domain-ajax-request-proxy-json.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is XSS and it is forbidden. You should really not do things that way.

If you really need to, make your AJAX code call the local code (PHP, ASP, whatever) on blah.com and make it behave like client and fetch whatever you need from foo.com and return that back to the client. If you use PHP, you can do this with fopen('www.foo.com/blah.html', 'r') and then reading the contents as if it was a regular file.

Of course, allow_remote_url_fopen (or whatever it is called exactly) needs to be enabled in your php.ini.

Answer (score 6):

There is a [w3c proposal](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) for allowing sites to specify other sites which are allowed to make cross site queries to them. (Wikipedia might want to allow all request for articles, say, but google mail wouldn't want to allow requests - since this might allow any website open when you are logged into google mail to read your mail).

This might be available at some point in the future.

Comment: The current W3C proposal is called ["Cross-Origin Resource Sharing"](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/), commonly known as **`CORS`**.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned above JSONP is a way around this.  However, the site that you are requesting the data from needs to support JSONP in order for you to use on the client. (JSONP essentially injects a script tag into the page, and provides a callback function that should be called with the results)

If the site you are making a request to does not support JSONP you will have to proxy the request on your server.  As mentioned above you can do this on your own server or what I have done in the past is use a http://www.jsonpit.com, which will proxy the request for you.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to implement a proxy page which takes the needed url as a parameter. e.g. http://blah.com/proxy?uri=http://foo.com/actualRequest

Comment: You'd better do a little validation on it to make sure that the URL is one that you expect... otherwise it is a major security hole.

Answer (score 1):

JSONP was partially designed to get around the problem you are having

http://ajaxian.com/archives/jsonp-json-with-padding

JQuery has it in their $.getJSON method

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON

Answer (score 0):

The method shown above could become a large security hole.
Suggest you verify the site name against a white list and build the actual URI being proxied on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

For cross domain hits this is a good working example and now is considered as some what "standard" http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2005/12/21/json-dynamic-script-tag.html.

there are other ways as well, for eg injecting iframes with document.domain altered

http://fettig.net/weblog/2005/11/28/how-to-make-xmlhttprequest-connections-to-another-server-in-your-domain/

I still agre that the easy way is calling a proxy in same domain but then it's not truly client side WS call.