# How to read xml file using JS

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, google-chrome

I am using the following code to read the xml file from JS

```
function ReadFile(xmlPath) {

  oxmlhttp = null;

  try {
    // Firefox, Chrome, etc... Browsers
    oxmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oxmlhttp.overrideMimeType("text/xml");
  } catch (e) {

    try {
        // IE Browser
        oxmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        return null;
    }
  }

  if (!oxmlhttp) return null;

  try {
     oxmlhttp.open("GET", xmlPath, false);
     oxmlhttp.send(null);
  } catch (e) {
     return null;
  }

  var xmlDoc = oxmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement;
  alert(xmlDoc);
  return oxmlhttp.responseText;

}
```

It's working fine for IE and Firefox but not in Chrome. the following exception "XMLHttpRequest cannot load the file. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP." should occur when i use chrome.

Can anybody know how to read the xml file in chrome using JS?

Answer (score 1):

According to the error, there is some problem with the request domain. You shold alert the domain address  of the request:

```
...
try {
   alert(xmlPath) //alerting
   oxmlhttp.open("GET", xmlPath, false);
   oxmlhttp.send(null);
} catch (e) {
   return null;
}
...
```

and the xmlPath sould not contain and another domain address.
read this issue aboute this: [Cross domain Ajax request from within js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319065/cross-domain-ajax-request-from-within-js-file)

Comment: I am curious that Firefox and IE load the XML correctly where they shouldn't. Don't they block cross-origin XHR?

Comment: they do. the problem would be some browser specific probblem. you shoudl alert your code and see what is it, and change if not correct.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Ya, i tried it, actually i am reading a xml file from local machine memory.

Answer (score 0):

Are you serving the xml file, or are you making tests using your file system ?

If you're using the file system, I'd recommend starting a small HTTP server on your site dir instead.

You can easily start a HTTP server to serve a directory, e.g. serve the current directory with Python:

```
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Or if you're using Windows, maybe you'll like HFS better for the same purpose: http://www.rejetto.com/hfs/

Cheers!