# getJSON and ajax not working in IE

Tags: ajax, json, internet-explorer, jquery

I am trying to get getJSON working on my IE, but I read that IE doesn't support it that well. So I decided to use ajax instead.

My code is:

```
$.ajax({
   dataType: 'json',
   url: 'http://openexchangerates.org/latest.json',
   success: function(data)
   {
       alert('done');
   }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Where did you read that? I'm not aware of any such issues. What is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make crossdomain ajax calls. Take a look at the top post at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319065/cross-domain-ajax-request-from-within-js-file). If you have a specific need to do so, you need to use some sort of sockets. This can be [file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents) in php or another server-side language

Comment: jQuery will use JSONP for that.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem just the other day. Internet Explorer doesn't like you doing cross-domain requests with AJAX.

I solved it by having a server-side script do the cross-domain API request, and then call the result of that script in my AJAX call.

Comment: this is not a IE issue, its the design of ajax itself.

Comment: I'm sorry, but why does that deserve a down-vote? I had a cross-domain request working in Chrome and Firefox, but not IE. Therefore, it's specific to IE.