# Send and receive data to and from another domain

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, xmlhttprequest, jsonp

I'm trying to write a plugin. I can not use any libraries or frameworks.
At any website (domain) I would like to start a script from my own domain.

For example:
In the code of the website under **domain A** I put a code starting the script from **domain B**

```
<script src="http://domain-b.com/myscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The code of JavaScript (myscript.js)

```
type = 'GET';
url = 'http://domain-b.com/echojson.php';
data = ‘var1=1&var2=2’;

_http = new XMLHttpRequest();

_http.open(type, url + '?callback=jsonp123' + '&' + data, true);
_http.onreadystatechange = function() {
      alert(‘Get data: ’ + _http.responseText);
}
_http.send(null);
```

*Script from **http://domain-b.com/echojson.php** always gives the answer:*

```
jsonp123({answer:”answer string”});
```

But in a JavaScript console I see an error (200) and AJAX doesn’t get anything.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319065/cross-domain-ajax-request-from-within-js-file

Answer (score 0):

Script loaders like LAB, yep/nope or [Frame.js](https://github.com/bishopZ/Frame.js) were designed to get around the same-origin policy. They load a script file, so the requested file would have to look like:

```
response = {answer:”answer string”};
```

Comment: Also, just noticed, jQuery added a crossDomain:true option in version 1.5 to enable limited cross-domain requests.

Answer (score 0):

If you use your code like you have posted it here, it does not work, because you are using apostrophs for the `data` variable!